# Is there an elegant way to send query results directly to a physical printer?

Tags: sql-server

I've got this weird request to have a report be scheduled *and printed to a printer*.

The report itself is pretty simple, and will fit on a single page. I can print it to a txt and that will be just fine (although I'm open to suggestions on a better product).

Here's the code. It works. But I don't like it. Specifically, Id like to do away with the nested @bcp and @SQL.

**Question:** Is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
declare @filepath varchar(255),
@filename varchar(255),
@filetype varchar(255),
@sql nvarchar(max),
@coverpage_text nvarchar(max)

set @filepath = 'C:\users\jmay\documents\'
SET @filename = 'TestFile'
set @filetype = '.txt'

--output to txt
set @sql = N'declare @bcp varchar(4000)
set @bcp = ''bcp " select * from test_data " queryout ' 
+ @filepath +  @filename + @filetype + ' -t " - " -c -T -d DBA''
print @bcp

EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @BCP'

print @sql
 exec sp_executesql @sql

--print data
 set @sql = N'declare @bcp varchar(4000)
set @bcp = ''START /MIN NOTEPAD /P ' + @filepath +  @filename +  @filetype + '''
print @bcp

EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @BCP'

print @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Execute the query using `POWERSHELL` and [OUT-PRINTER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-printer?view=powershell-5.1)

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT GETDATE() AS TimeOfQuery;" -ServerInstance .   | Out-Printer
```

> The Out-Printer cmdlet sends output to the default printer or to an
>   alternate printer, if one is specified.

Comment: It worked like magic, the same code can shorten down to:

 Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT * from dba..test_data;"   | Out-Printer
  
I scheduled it as a job and bam. thanks for your help!